# How to handle URL in searching technique in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am implementing searching feature in my job portal website.
In that, I used "get" method for searching, that is url will display keywords. 
For example 

`www.domain.com/search.php?keyword=php&location=lodon` 
In above URL searched keyword is "php", selected location is "london".

I want to display URL like

```
www.domain.com/search/php-jobs-in-london
```

How to rewrite this using htaccess in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never done something exactly like this, but I am going to at least try to give you a place to start.

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z]+)-jobs-in-([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search.php?keyword=$1&location=$2 [NC,L]
```

The Lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Make the RewriteRule not be valid when trying to access a file or a directory.

The Third is the important one, because it formats the URL, each parenthesis will be a parameter that you will pass to the actual URL through GET method.

To understand the meaning of the expression you
can look here: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php